# wpf mvvm treeview contexmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I'm learning WPF/MVVM and got stuck on following...
The code below is working

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
  <ListBox.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
         <MenuItem Header="Show Selected" 
         Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowSelectedCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}"/>
      </ContextMenu>
  </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

but when I've replaced listbox on treeview, such as

```
<TreeView x:Name="tview"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu  DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpen="true">
                        <MenuItem Header="Show Selected" Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowSelectedCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}">
                             </MenuItem>
                         </ContextMenu>
                </TreeView.ContextMenu>
            </TreeView>
```

The ShowSelectedCommand doesn't invoked. Could you please explain what's wrong there and how can I make it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try to debug your ShowSelectedCommand? You're binding the CommandParameter to the SelectedItems. In a ListView (
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) there's this property. But have a look at the TreeView (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) - there's no SelectedItems property.

Comment: Does output provide any error?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. well, except `CommandParameter`for tree-view was null because there is no `SelectedItems` in `TreeView` but other than that, it worked fine and the command got invoked in both controls. I think there is something else causing the issue and I suggest you to put a dummy `IValueConverter` in your command binding like this : `Command="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource dummyConverter}}"` and test your binding.